# Trouble installing CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm installing some dependencies on my Xcode workspace using CocoaPods... This the terminal output:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Oscar:EM-iOS Swanros$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.21.0.rc1 is available.

/Users/Swanros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/xcodeproj-0.6.0/ext/xcodeproj/xcodeproj_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Abort trap: 6
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would first try uninstalling and reinstalling CocoaPods.

```
[sudo] gem uninstall cocoapods
```

then

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: This worked! Just made sure to remove all versions. Looks like I had 2 versions of cocoa pods installed.

Comment: I had this error because I installed it with brew. So I uninstalled it with `brew uninstall cocoapods` and used the command above instead.

Comment: @Tulleb Same thing. Installed with `brew`, had the error in OP's question, removed with `brew` and reinstalled with `gem`.